# Override add() method to private Set<> in another class Java?

Tags: java, oop, overriding, private

I have 2 Java files: File 1 is a given data structure class with methods for a Set and I am not allowed to modify this class at all. File 2 is a class I am making which overrides the `add()` function in File 1.

*File 1*

```
public class MySetClass<E> {
    private final Set<E> set = new HashSet<E>();  //is private

    public boolean add(E element){
        return set.add(element);
    }
 }
```

*File 2*

```
public class OverrideMySetClass<E> extends MySetClass<E> {
    @Override
    public boolean add(E element) {
        System.out.println("Overriden Add");
        return set.add(element);      //ERR: MySetClass<E>.set is not visible (I know it's bc it's private)
    }
}
```

My question is how do I add items to a set that's not visible to the method that should be overriding `add()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `super.add(element)`

In the same way as `this` refers to the current object, `super` refers to its direct parent